# C# simulating a system crash

Tags: c#, c++, database, testing

How can I simulate a system crash or power outage in c#/c++?

I am writing a library that works similar to a database and needs to implement some aspects of transaction principle of typical sql databases. The library has one method in which it has to make sure all data is written out to hard drive (using the win api function FlushFileBuffers). After this line the library will consider the transaction as completed. After some research I found out that FlushFileBuffers isn't reliable e.g. the hard drive could just return that all buffers are flushed even so this isn't the case. I need a way to immediately kill my system after the call of FlushFileBuffers to check if the data was actually written out after the line of code. This could look like this:

```
writeToFile(fileHandle);
FlushFileBuffers(fileHandle);
killSystem(); //this is missing
```

On the next restart of the system I could check if the data was actually written out. If there isn't a way to kill the system is there any other scenario I could use to test this? All ideas are welcome!

Comment: Run it inside a VM and crash (or "kill -9") the VM host process.

Comment: (I have no idea how one would synchronize the process though.)

Comment: One thing you can do is to have a program which enumerates processes and kills each one but itself. It should be done in a loop and inner killing should be try-catched. Run such a program on admin privileges and your OS will shut in a speed of light :D

Comment: Side note: It would be so much easier if you just write proper unit test for that code... (like mock "file system" and than check how your system behaves with partial writes).

Comment: I am using unit tests and all methods are tested using a mock file system. The problem lays in win api, the real file system, drivers and hardware so it is not part of my program but sadly part of my responsibility. I need to test these too to be sure my system works correctly.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes this may work. Main problem is the synchronization. Maybe I can send a message over network to the host system which then kills the VM using the method Measuring suggests. But sending message could be too slow and gives the system/hardware enough time to flush their buffers :/

Comment: Maybe follow [SQLite's lead](http://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html): "We are told that the flush and fsync primitives are broken on some versions of Windows and Linux. This is unfortunate. It opens SQLite up to the possibility of database corruption following a power loss in the middle of a commit. However, *there is nothing that SQLite can do to test for or remedy the situation*. SQLite assumes that the operating system that it is running on works as advertised. If that is not quite the case, well then hopefully you will not lose power too often."

Comment: Also from [SQLites WAL overview](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) (compared to the rollback journal): "WAL uses many fewer fsync() operations and is thus less vulnerable to problems on systems where the fsync() system call is broken."

Comment: Well not really unit test - but you should be able to mock file IO and implement whatever failures you want in consistent and repeatable manner. Reliable storage on non-reliable medium is hard problem so it should be perfectly ok to spent large amount of time on mock system that allows you to reliably introduce failures.

Answer (score 2):

Calling TerminateProcess should not allow any process to do cleanup.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get the process.
    Process target = Process.GetProcesses()
        .First(p => 
               p.ProcessName.IndexOf("VMWare",
                                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    // Headshot!
    TerminateProcess(target.Handle, 0);
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool TerminateProcess(IntPtr hProcess, int uExitCode);
```

Using a virtual machine as suggested by user2864740 and killing it with the above method might give the desired effect.

Read more about [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If I use this directly on my application it will still flush all the buffers e.g. even without FlushFileBuffers all the files will be correctly written out. (but they will be corrupted if I unplug my pc). But you mean I should run my application in a VM and then kill the VM? That may work. It will take me some time to test ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of parallels is to not simulate it in the first place. They have a tool to write numbers to the hard drive and send it out to the server at the same time. You actively pull the plug of the pc and reboot it. The tool will after reboot check if the number on harddrive is smaller than the one on the number. If this is the case flushing to harddrive didn't work.

Not pretty but should work ...